# curl- java for github repository creation

Tags: java, github, curl

I am using java code to create a github repo. i am using the curl to achieve it.
Curl command works fine from command-line. But it's not working from java. Below is my java code snippet:

```
String command2="curl -u id:token https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos -d {\"name\":\"New1\"}";
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);
```

Could you please suggest why it's not working from java code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue - there was a parsing error. But now, on successful repository creation, my code is not ending - it's running continuously, below is my code snippet:

```
String command2="curl -u id:token https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos -d {\\\"name\\\":\\\"New6\\\"}";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command2.split(" "));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
InputStream response = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
System.out.println("output: ");
while(process.isAlive()) Thread.sleep(30);
reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
reader.lines().forEach(System.err::println);
System.out.println("---");   
process.destroy();
```